# Wiring RS485 - RFID

Tags: rfid, rs485

I am new to using this device, I trying to get the numbering of rfid iclass card with a HID reader (HID® iCLASS SE® R10) via usb converter rs485 (a COM port is generated in windows)

I Try with this combination:

Pigtail   < ------- > USB RS485 CONVERTER

```
Black     <---------> 3 and battery
Green     <---------> 4
White     <---------> 1

Black     <---------> 3 and battery
Green     <---------> 1
White     <---------> 4

Black     <---------> 3 and battery
Red/Green <---------> 1
Tan       <---------> 4

Black     <---------> 3 and battery
Red/Green <---------> 4
Tan       <---------> 1
```

None of the above give me data when I approach the card (The reader sounds and I am using Docklight to read the response)

Could you please guide me with the correct wiring?
I tried many combinations but none works

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem.

[image: Converter]

[image]

Comment: You can't connect the wiegand pins to 485, so first two suggestions are wrong. Also the second two suggestions are wrong, because you are connecting to one transmit pin and one receive pin on the USB plug. Please read the manuals of these devices how to best connect them (because we don't have them or don't know which devices they are so we can't find them, and basically, asking how to use electronic devices is off-topic so this question most likely gets closed).

Comment: I'd say check the user manual for both of these things, from the panel there is probably some configuration or jumper to be set before if can be used.

Comment: I understand that the wiring may be bad. But this was an attempt reading below that the rfid reader supports rs485, I had an old reader that had the same configuration but it was pigtal to rs232 and rs232 to usb and works fine in windows